# list of numpy arrays instead of one hot vector

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, machine-learning, keras

for neuronal network i need to convert labels to one hot array.
I have 3 labels that appear in a list like :

```
labels = ["Synonym", "Antonym", "Not relevant", "Synonym", "Antonym"]
```

There are 3 different labels and I want first to refer them to numbers 1,2 and 3 and then build one hot vector from them, like for example for label 3 --> 0 0 1 The function that I have make list of arrays and that doesnt work than for training.

```
def label_to_onehot(labels):
    mapping = {label: i for i, label in enumerate(set(labels))}

one_hot = []
for label in labels:
    entry = [0] * len(mapping)
    entry[mapping[label]] = 1
    one_hot.append(entry)
return one_hot
```

That is what i get:

> ValueError: Error when checking model target: the list of Numpy arrays that you are passing to your model is not the size the model
>   expected. Expected to see 1 array(s), but instead got the following
>   list of 165757 arrays: [array([[0],
>          [0],
>          [1]]), array([[1],
>          [0],
>          [0]]), array([[0],
>          [1],

Comment: Try returning ```np.array(one_hot)```. You didn't mention which model you are using but It might expect an array instead of list of arrays.

Comment: This is what you get when you *run what??*

Comment: here is a code https://www.jdoodle.com/python3-programming-online#&togetherjs=1oQB1To2ND

Comment: when i try np.array(one_hot) i get:
Epoch 1/7
2019-01-13 17:25:18.816043: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:141] Your CPU supports instructions that this TensorFlow binary was not compiled to use: AVX2 FMA
Traceback (most recent call last):.....ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keras was expecting a numpy array of shape `(batch_size, classes)`. But you gave the input as python list which doesn't have the `shape` attribute to retrieve batch size and classes. Hence, even though size is correct but type is wrong.

One possible solution is:
Where a is your mapped indices and c is total number of classes.

```
def one(a, c):
     out = []
     for i in a:
             entry = [0 for i in range(c)]
             entry[i] = 1
             out.append(entry)
     return np.array(out)
```

Alternatively you can also use `to_categorical` in `keras.utils`

```
from keras.utils import to_categorical
a = to_categorical(a, c)
```